# How does firebase handle targeted users in ab testing?

Tags: firebase, ab-testing, firebase-remote-config

recently I am playing with AB testing on firebase, and I have got a question about user targeting and distribution.

The big question is: **How does firebase ab testing handle targeted user pool if the value of the criterion received from user is changeable?**

Let's say I have targeted users whose region matches United States, and one of the targeted user leaves United States to France while the ab testing is still running. So technically the region of that user should become France instead of United States, which makes that user not match the criterions. Therefore, is that user still targeted in the ab testing? Or that user will be removed from the targeted user pool?

If firebase keep the user in the pool, this is weird because the user is no longer matching the criterion.

If firebase remove the user from the pool, which means the targeted users in an ab testing can be dynamically changing. Is it ok for an ab testing?

Does anyone know how firebase is handling this?

Answer (score 0):

"[user is a permanent member of an audience after they are assigned to it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/config-analytics#remote_config_and_user_properties)" which applies for an A/B testing as well.

So if you choose to test user from US and he moves to France, he stays in the test group even if he is no longer in US.

Comment: Here is the update (as for 2020-02-12)
"As Firebase gets new data about users, their audience memberships are reevaluated to ensure they still meet the audience criteria. If the latest data indicate they no longer meet the criteria, they are removed from those audiences."
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317509

Comment: I believe that doesn't affect the ABT experiment though. Once a user is assigned a variant they stay assigned.